# Is it possible to control a scrollable jquery ui dialog using keys (PgUp, PgDn, ... spacebar?...)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, scroll

I have a jQuery UI dialog that has enough content to trigger the appearance of vertical scroll bars.  I found that the only way to make it scroll was to either click-and-drag the scrollbar, or click in the scrollbar area - i.e. it was not possible to make it scroll using the PgUp or PgDn keys, nor the arrow keys or spacebar, etc.  What would be the best way to enable keyboard activated scrolling?

[Note: I'm actually using an enhanced version of the jQuery UI dialog (http://www.fieryprophet.com/demo/jqui-dialog-minmax/) but have found the same issue with the normal one.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be schieved, by adding the attribute *tabindex* to the dialog container *div*, to make it accept key events. E.g.:

```
<div id="dialog" tabindex="-1">
  very much content here ...
</div>
```

You can also add this to the *open* method of the dialog:

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
    open: function(e, ui) {
        var $dlg = $(e.target);
        if ($dlg.is(':visible')) {
            $dlg.focus();
        }
    }
});
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jx5xe3fb/) for a working example. (Of course, setting the foucs in a JSFIddle  does not really work the same way as in a standalone page).

See documentation of [.focus()](http://api.jquery.com/focus/): "*Attempting to set focus to a hidden element causes an error in Internet Explorer.*".

See "[Making Elements Focusable with Tabindex](http://snook.ca/archives/accessibility_and_usability/elements_focusable_with_tabindex)" for a good description what *tabindex="-1** does.

Answer (score 1):

You could bind and event handler to the `keyup` event of the window and if the key pressed is PgUP or PgDown or anything you decide, you can scroll the dialog. Something like this:

```
$(window).keydown(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}

$(window).keypress(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}

$(window).keyup(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var curScroll = $("#content").scrollTop();

    switch(event.which) {
        case 32:
        case 34:
            curFocus.scrollTop(curScroll + 100);
            break;
        case 33:
            curFocus.scrollTop(curScroll - 100);
            break;
    }
});
```

I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/goffreder/PfY6N/4/) to explain better my solution.

EDIT: added the `event.preventDefault()` to the keyboard event handlers to avoid the scrolling of the page.

UPDATE: apparently a dialog does not raise the simple `focus` or `blur` events, nor does the body. I added a bit of instruction to make only the focused element scrollable, or the window if there's none.

```
var curFocus = $(window);

$("#content").on("dialogfocus", function() {
    curFocus = $(this);
});

$("body").click(function(event) {
    if((event.target) != $("#content")[0])
        curFocus = $(window);
});
```

Comment: I don't get it.  1. There is no javascript code in your jsFiddle example: it is just showing the normal behaviour.  2. I want to have the ability of having either the dialog scroll or the panels, depending on which have focus.  Right now I have various panels, which can get focus and scroll fine using keyboard events.  It is just the dialog window that does not scroll.

Comment: I'm sorry, there must have been some mistake while I was saving the fiddle, now it should work.

In my example there's only one dialog, but you can add an instruction in the `keyup` handler that triggers the scroll only for the focused dialog.

Comment: Yes, it does scroll, thanks.  The problem is that the entire page will scroll as well. I have modified your fiddle to illustrate this: http://jsfiddle.net/aroberge/PfY6N/.    By contrast, if one has a panel with scrollable content having the focus, only the panel will scroll (unless it can no longer scroll after which the entire page will scroll).

Comment: You need to prevent the default behaviour of the page by adding `event.preventDefault()` to the keyboard events handler, so you can choose what has to scroll and what not every time the keys are pressed. I edited the fiddle to make only the dialog scrollable by pressing PgDown, look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/goffreder/PfY6N/2/).

Comment: Thanks for looking at it again.  I guess I did not explain properly what I am trying to do.  I want to use a dialog window as a "help" window that can be easily scrolled when it has focus, but is ignored when the focus is elsewhere. Take jsfiddle; if you click in one area (say the hmtl content) that has scrollbars, then these get "activated" when you press PgUp, PgDn, etc.  If you click elsewhere, to give focus to some other area, then it is that new selection that can be controlled (scrolled) using the keyboard.  What I want is for a dialog window to behave the same way.

Comment: I have found a plugin, mbcontainerplus, which does what I need and which I may use instead - although it is not exactly lightweight.

Comment: As I said before, you can choose to scroll only the field that has focus in the `keydown` event handler. Something like `$(":focus").scrollTop(...)`, which selects the element with the focus and scrolls it. It can be the window, a dialog, a div, etc...

Comment: I updated the fiddle, now if you click on the dialog, it gains focus and pressing PgUp, Down or spacebar will scroll it. If you click outside of the dialog, the focused element becomes the window, and the scroll is applied to it. Is this the behaviour you wanted?

Comment: It's almost right  (need to be able to scroll down the dialog more than once ... but that should be enough for me to fiddle and make it work). Thanks for the best answer!